# How do I log every time I start an application in Windows?

Tags: java, .net, windows

I'd like to log or record every time I start an application to gain insight into which applications I use most on my Windows system.  I was thinking I could create an event in the event log and listen for it in a .Net program.
Questions:

- Is this the best way to solve this problem?
- If so, which .Net library should I use?

I am also open to using Java to solve this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try to hook the CreateProcess API in system wide using unmanaged c++.
and in C# use .NET interop to handle events/notifies from you unmanaged hook module.

related links:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx?msg=1322916
http://www.madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, you could probably create a shell extension which you would register for EXE programs which would really just be a filter for the EXE extension.  When your shell extension is called, you would execute the program (by invoking the old functionality) after you logged your information.

Note, however, that you can ONLY do this with .NET 4.0 or above, which is currently in beta.  Because of the way that previous versions of the CLR worked, only one version was allowed to run in a process at a time (including explorer, the OS process).

.NET 4.0 introduces Side-by-Side (SxS) CLR instances within the same process, so it is safe to use it from .NET 4.0 on as a mechanism for shell extensions.

It will also require a good deal of COM interop, but it can be done.

---

In regards to LWoodyiii's comment asking if this can be done in older versions of .NET: Could it?  Yes, it *can* be done, but the official decree from MS is that you shouldn't.  The reason for this is because if someone else decides to run a shell extension, or interface with the OS in some way using .NET, and the version is different from the one that you are using, you run the risk of hosing the OS process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This seems a little complicated; plus it depends on .Net 4.0.  Anything that would work in an older version of .Net?  Thanks again.